# Load passworded word document in richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I opened word document in richtextbox using

```
richTextBoxEx1.LoadFile(@"c:\3.docx", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

But how to open passworded word document ?
How to bypass the password to richtextbox ?

Comment: I would recommend to load the file early in your code (Maybe there you can put the password) and then assing to the textbox the RTF from the word document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a password protected word document using interop and then save it in rft format (that is not password protected) and can be shown flowless.

First add a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`

Then create a form with a `RichTextBox` on it and use these codes:

```
private delegate void OpenRtfDelegate();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Create word application
        var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        //Attach an eventn handler to word_Quit to open rft file after word quit.
        //If you try to load rtf before word quit, you will receive an exception that says file is in use.
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)word).Quit += word_Quit; 

        //Open word document
        var document = word.Documents.Open(@"Path_To_Word_File.docx", PasswordDocument: "Password_Of_Word_File");

        //Save as rft
        document.SaveAs2(@"Path_To_RFT_File.rtf", FileFormat: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatRTF);

        //Quit word
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application)word).Quit(SaveChanges: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void word_Quit()
{
    //You should load rtf this way, because word_Quit is running in a differet thread
    this.richTextBox1.BeginInvoke(new OpenRtfDelegate(OpenRtf));
}

private void OpenRtf()
{
    this.richTextBox1.LoadFile(@"Path_To_RFT_File.rtf");
}
```

You can format and bend the code to your requirement.

Comment: Office Interop is often considered "depreciated" by many, [Open XML for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) is considered the "modern" way to do it and has the added benitfit that it does not require to have Word installed on the machine for the program to work.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You are right in cases that the job will be done without using Office. But here the developer needs to convert word to rtf and as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10204931/3110834) the Open XML sdk doesn't allow to convert to other document formats itself so other options including Office Interop should be considered.

Comment: Open XML sdk doesn't doesn't support password documents

Comment: @MahmoudElgindy I'm not familiar with open xml sdk. If you know any reference which shows it doesn't support password protected documents it's good to post it in comments. Another problem of open xml sdk here is because it doesn't support converting to rtf.

Comment: There isn't any code for opening password protected docx on Microsoft site beside a asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380309/open-protected-word-document-with-openxml